# How to include CSS and JS files from other folder?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html file put in D:\xampp\htdocs\example.html.
My CSS and JS put in system temp dir: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cache.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cache\css\jquery.autocomplete.1415346106.css' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cache\js\jquery.min.1415354295.js'></script>
```

I tried to insert CSS and JS files at `example.html` as above code, but it doesn't work.
Please help me for this.

Comment: You need a webserver read about "wamp"

Comment: Your web assets must be located in a web accessible folder, and I doubt that `C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\cache` is configured to be.

Comment: @skv - Judging by his link, `D:\xampp\htdocs\example.html`, I'd guess he's using XAMPP.

Comment: True, I was too "lazy" :) but yes the idea is to use the server and not rely on file

Comment: I guess your XAMPP does not have the permission to access the requested file. Take a look into your dev tools what's the reason for that. Or maybe you don't access your file through localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Generally not a good approach to include public files from folders outside of your application.
Also the fact that you include them from a temp cache folder raises questions.

Why dont you create a new folder inside your htdocs. call it static. Inside this folder you create 2 new folders called javascript and css. Now put the js file inside the javascript folder. do the same for the css file.

from your index.html you include it with a relative path:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='static/css/jquery.autocomplete.1415346106.css' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='static/javascript/jquery.min.1415354295.js'></script>
```

Comment: My app will generate any CSS, JS temp files. And i want to put them into temp folder of OS (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have XXAMP as a web server running. Be sure to have Apache web server running, and move you HTML/CCC/JavaScript files over to the XXAMP web folder (which in your case is D:\xampp\htdocs), and you will then access your webpage through browser at http:\localhost (in your case http:\localhost/example.html)

I would make a folders at D:\xampp\htdocs\css and D:\xampp\htdocs\js, and place your css and javascript into these folders. You then edit your example.html file to read:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css\jquery.autocomplete.1415346106.css' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='js\jquery.min.1415354295.js'></script>
```

Comment: i need put them into a folder as outsite web server (temp folder of OS)